# Applying dictionary comprehension to a defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, defaultdict, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following, which parses three columns of tabular data (an openpyxl worksheet) into a `defaultdict`.

```
def campaigns_and_adsets_and_pageviews_from_ga(ourTab):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for row in ourTab.rows[1:-1]:
        if ('Facebook' in row[0].value) and ('(not set)' not in row[2].value):
            d[row[1].value][row[2].value] += row[4].value
    return d
```

The output of which looks like the following:

```
In [790]: campaigns_and_adsets_and_pageviews_from_ga(ourTab)
Out[790]: 
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {u'XXX 20160314': defaultdict(int,
                         {u'Carnival desktopfeed': 2.0,
                          u'Carnival mobilefeed': 588.0,
                          u'PYS Broad desktopfeed': 371.0,
                          u'PYS Broad mobilefeed': 1192.0}),
             u'YYY Intl 20150903': defaultdict(int,
                         {u'CA desktopfeed': 2.0}),
```

What I want to do is multiply the final value in each element (i.e. 2.0, 588.0 etc.) by a constant, resulting in another `defaultdict` (or even a regular nested `dict` would be fine).

Can the defaultdict be deconstructed somehow back into a nested dict in order to allow the transformation to be possible? Or what other approaches are possible?

Comment: You forgot to call the function.

Comment: You need `.items()` so you're actually working through the entries.

Comment: In view of two bugs being spotted immediately, I suggest you first bodge/mock your `campaigns_and_adsets_and_pageviews_from_ga` function to return just a dictionary literal defining the nested dictionaries (never mind `defaultdict` yet): `return {u'XXX 20160314' : {u'Carnival desktopfeed': 2.0, ... }}`. Then write code that correctly copies it and doubles the numbers. Then switch back to returning the `defaultdict` with the computed results. That way you won't be distracted by assuming that everything which goes wrong must be to do with `defaultdict` :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Fair point, well made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a simple recursive function that multiplies the numbers with given value and for every `dict` instance constructs a new dictionary:

```
from numbers import Number

def multiply(o, mul):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k: multiply(v, mul) for k, v in o.items()}
    elif isinstance(o, Number):
        return o * mul
    else:
        return o
```

Given your example `defaultdict` and multiplier `2` as input the output looks following:

```
{
    u'YYY Intl 20150903': {u'CA desktopfeed': 4.0}, 
    u'XXX 20160314': {
        u'Carnival desktopfeed': 4.0, 
        u'PYS Broad desktopfeed': 742.0, 
        u'PYS Broad mobilefeed': 2384.0, 
        u'Carnival mobilefeed': 1176.0
    }
}
```

Note that the example doesn't work with lists, for those you'd need to add some more code.

Comment: Now *that's* thinking outside of the box. Was not aware of the `numbers` module. Thank you on both fronts.

Comment: @Pyderman: Had to search it too after I figured that there needs to be an easier way than handling `float` and `int` separately.